# A Java Set for at most 2 objects

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm writing a method that returns a `Set<String>`. The set may contain 0, 1, or 2 objects. The string keys are also quite small (maximum 8 characters). The set is then used in a tight loop with many iterations calling `contains()`.

For 0 objects, I would return `Collections.emptySet()`.

For 1 object, I would return `Collections.singleton()`.

For 2 objects (the maximum possible number), a `HashSet` seems overkill. Isn't there a better structure? Maybe a `TreeSet` is slightly better? Unfortunately, I'm still using Java 7 :-( so can't use modern things like `Set.of()`.

An array of 2 strings would probably give the best performance, but that's not a Set. I want the code to be self-documenting, so I really want to return a Set as that is the logical interface required.

Comment: If you're using java 9, `Set.of("one", "two")` will give you an optimized immutable set of a type specifically made for 2 elements.

Comment: If you're using pre Java 9, just extend [`AbstractSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) to wrap an array.

Comment: Why don't you use your array and encapsulate it in a `Set` interface? ie prevent that the same item is added twice.

Comment: In Java 8 and before just use Guava's `ImmutableSet`. But if you're using at most 2 objects anyways an array may be the best option.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I'm using Java 7 :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The set is then used in a tight loop with many iterations calling contains().

I would probably streamline it for this. Perhaps something like:

```
public static class TwoSet<T> extends AbstractSet<T> {
    T a = null;
    T b = null;

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return o.equals(a) || o.equals(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        if(contains(t)){
            return false;
        }
        if ( a == null ) {
            a = t;
        } else if ( b == null ) {
            b = t;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot have more than two items in this set.");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if(o.equals(a)) {
            a = null;
            return true;
        }
        if(o.equals(b)) {
            b = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return (a == null ? 0 : 1) + (b == null ? 0 : 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        List<T> list;
        if (a == null && b == null) {
            list = Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            if (a == null) {
                list = Arrays.asList(b);
            } else if (b == null) {
                list = Arrays.asList(a);
            } else {
                list = Arrays.asList(a, b);
            }
        }
        return list.iterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say I wanted an immutable set, so no need to define `add()` (although it might be useful for future readers). Also `Collections.singletonList(a)` is more efficient than `Arrays.asList(a)`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - Making it immutable is quite simple, just throw exceptions for `add` and `remove` and add a couple of constructors. The generated lists are only for iteration but by all means use `singletonList`.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap an array with an `AbstractSet`. You only have to implement 2 methods, assuming you want an unmodifiable set:

```
  class SSet extends AbstractSet<String> {
    private final String[] strings;

    SSet(String[] strings) {
      this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return Arrays.asList(strings).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return strings.length;
    }
  }
```

If you want, you can store the `Arrays.asList(strings)` in the field instead of a `String[]`. You can also provide 0, 1 and 2-arg constructors if you want to constrain the array only to be that length.

You can also override `contains`:

```
public boolean contains(Object obj) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
    if (Objects.equals(obj, strings[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you don't want to create a list simply to create an iterator, you can trivially implement one as an inner class:

```
class ArrayIterator implements Iterator<String> {
  int index;

  public String next() {
    // Check if index is in bounds, throw if not.
    return strings[index++];
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return index < strings.length;
  }

  // implement remove() too, throws UnsupportedException().
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

- Make a class that implements Set interface
- Override add and remove method
- Add value upon class initialisation by `super.add(E element)`
- Use that class instead